# Combine Two column values from Same table with IF Condition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table Company in SQL Server having columns CompCode, CompanyName ,CompanyTypecode . I want to combine ComanyName,CompanyTypeCode columns in Select Statement where if  CompanyTypecode is 1 then combine 'Headoffice' with CompanyName and if CompanyTypeCode is 2 then combine "Branch" with CompanyName

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    case
        when CompanyTypecode = 1 then 'Headoffice ' + CompanyName
        when CompanyTypecode = 2 then 'Branch ' + CompanyName
    end
from
    dbo.Company ;
```

[CASE in Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

*Am I missing something here? This seems pretty straightforward.*